# PHP PDO: cannot access views from Microsoft SQL

Tags: php, sql, json, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble access information in **"views"** from a MS SQL Server.

My intent is to return the information as JSON data to me handles from an AJAX call from another page.

I am using a standard PDO object to access information from several views instead of tables.  I can access the tables just fine and can return results.  So I know the code is working properly.

Once I tried to access a view I return 0 rows.

I am using a generic snippet to access

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=[x.x.x.x];Database=[DB_NAME]","[USER]", "[PW]");
    $sql = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [VIEW_NAME]";
    $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    var_dump($e);
}
while($r = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $json = json_encode($r);
}
if ($json == "") {
    echo "No Record Found...";
} else {
    echo $json;    
}
```

I can log into the SQL Studio with the username and PW and can run the query fine so I know it is not a permissions issue

Does anyone know of any issues accessing views

Comment: You know that your `$json` variable is overwritten on each iteration ? You could just use `$result->fetchAll()`

Comment: @Daan They only return one row anyway.

Comment: @JonStirling Didn't see the `TOP 1` thanks. In that case I rephrase my question. Why are you using a `while` loop?

Comment: Yes I only want to return one result.  Still that is good advice for me in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying that you've changed the SQL to query a table instead of a view and this exact code snippet works just fine?

Comment: To their point, using a loop/iterator on a resultset that can only contain a single record is pointless, and removes clarity from the script. Save `while()`, `foreach()`, `for()`, `do{}while()` loops for when you need to iterate over multiple records/array keys. Just a tip. 'Cause exactly what *could* happen, *did* happen. @Daan saw your `while()` loop and instantly thought it was iterating over multiple records. Just adds confusion.

Comment: Yes It works as long as I query tables and not views.  I don't know if it is something with the setup of the SQL Server.

Comment: @Daan the reason for the loop is the database has some duplicate information that returns more than one of the same result.  The query I am using checks for customer information based on their phone number from multiple views so the loop was a safety measure when that happened.

Comment: SOLVED: because the views access other databases that I did NOT have permission that cause 0 results.  I was logged on to the SQL Studio as the sa so i got a false impression that the username had permission.  Added permission to the other DB and worked.  Thanks Anyway.